# collision detection using bounding boxes slowing aframe down

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

Hi I recently made a component for collision detection among primitive and non primitive shapes. I was using bounding box collision provided in three.js.. its working fine but when I am using it for custom objects its slowing the entire experience down... kindly look into my component and tell me whats the issue...

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('manual-body', {
          matchingElements: function(attribute){
            var matchingElements = [];
            var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
            for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++){
              if (allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute) !== null){
                // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
                matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
              }
            }
            return matchingElements;
          },
          tick: function(){
            var elements=this.matchingElements('manual-body');
            for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
              if(this.el.id==elements[i].id){
                continue;
              }
              firstBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(elements[i].object3D);
              secondBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.el.object3D);
              var collision = firstBB.intersectsBox(secondBB);
              if(collision){
                this.el.emit('collision', {elSource: this.el,elTarget:elements[i]});
              }
            }
          }
        });
```

What do you think might be the cause of the lag? is it the collision logic inside the tick function or is it something else.....

Thanks

Comment: By custom objects, You mean non 'boxy' models ?

Comment: by custom objects/non primitive shapes i meant 3d obejcts taken from here https://free3d.com/ in .obj format.... when attaching the component with them its slowing down the experience....

Comment: It could be happening, because three has problems with adjusting the box to Your model. Can You create a invisible box within the model, and make the intersection checks with it ?

Comment: Are you asking me to check collision of the 3d object with other models if you are asking that, I did intersection checks with it with a primitive shape (a-box) the collision detection was fine .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `THREE.Box3().setFromObject` works by looping over every vertex in a model to determine the bounding box. This is too much work to run every frame in your `tick` for complex models.

You may want to check out [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras) sphere-collider component for efficient, approximate collisions

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that three.js is slowing down Your site by adjusting the box boundaries to the custom model.
 I would manually add a box entity inside Your model:

```
<a-entity collada-model="my model">
      <a-box></a-box>
</a-entity>
```

and make the collision checks with the boxes within.
If You are trying to make some kind of physics, try Don McCurdy's [Cannon.js implementation](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system), for there is no need to reinvent the wheel :P

**UPDATE**
If You have issues only with .obj's, and collada's are not causing issues, try converting the obj models to .dae. 
 If Your issue still exists, try my boundaries override.

Comment: I tried using dae object i.e. collada model.... those are working perfectly fine.

Comment: So You have only problems with some .obj's ?

Comment: Do you know why obj's are not working ??? it would be great if obj's could run as they are more common and available these days...

Comment: I have no idea why You have performance issues with .obj's, but if the same model will act differently as a .obj and .dae, it'll mean that it has problem with parsing the obj to the webGL api